# Was Code Geass first a light novel, manga, or anime?

Tags: code-geass

There are manga, light novel, and anime versions of Code Geass. Which came first?

Answer (score 6):

It was original, the anime came first then various adaptations. You could confirm this in [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1575/Code_Geass__Hangyaku_no_Lelouch). Under "Background":

> Code Geass: Hangyaku no Lelouch is an **original anime series** by Sunrise animation studio with original character designs by the all-female Japanese manga artist group Clamp.

(Emphasis added)

Just don't be surprised that some good shows are anime-original like Psycho Pass, Madoka, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to know it's anime original is that the wikipedia page calls Code Geass an anime. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Geass

Cf another 'anime' like Death Note: The wikipedia page calls Death Note a manga. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note

Of course it's just heuristic. The sure fire way is to scroll down the page and check the release/publication date.